# Set Outlook Profile Name c#

Tags: c#, email, outlook, appointment

I want to create a WebService in C#, which should generate Appointments from my Database (only Recepients MailAdresses, Start and End Date, ..) 
If I want to set this up and I type the following code:

`private Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();`

from which Mail Profile will the E-Mails and Appointments be sent?
Can I create a Name like: "MyAppointmentGenerator" in my WebService, which is displayed in the receiver`s Outlook, from whom the appointment is created/incoming?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook cannot be used from a service (such as IIS).

Why do you need Outlook at all? Create a MIME message with an iCalendar part and send it using SMTP.